# SQL job that runs a SELECT query only returns one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Long time reader but first time poster here. Hoping you can help me with some SQL im having trouble with. I am no expert so you may have to bear with me :-)

Im trying to schedule a SQL job to email a list of SQL sysadmins that exist on a SQL server using sp_send_dbmail. The problem I am having is that I have it working on one SQL server (emails a CSV attachment with 19 rows) but when I try exactly the same job on another 2 servers it only returns 1 row from the query (the sa account). If I take the SELECT query out of the job step and run it manually through a new query windows it returns the correct number of rows but if run as part of the job it only returns 1 row.

Im nearly sure it must be some access or privilege problem but I can figure our what. The job history shows the job running and finishing successfully.

Can anyone help? I'm really tearing my hair out with this one!

Here's the T-SQL that's entered into the job step.

Thanks!!

```
`EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'SQL DB Alerts',
@recipients = '<EmailAddressHere>',
@subject = 'SQL Sysadmins',
@execute_query_database = 'master',
@query = N'SELECT @@SERVERNAME as SQLServerName,
@@SERVICENAME as SQLInstanceName,
name as LoginName
FROM syslogins 
WHERE sysadmin = 1',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'ListofSysAdmins.csv',
@query_result_no_padding = 1,
@append_query_error = 0,
@exclude_query_output = 1,
@query_result_header = 1,
@query_result_separator='   '`
```

Comment: Not sure what DMV you are using,can you  use the run as option in job properties,to use sysadmin account

Comment: take a look a user who execute the job (query). Is an SQL user? a Domain user?

Answer (score 0):

The job needs to run under the security context of a sysadmin or securityadmin role member to return all the sysadmin role members. Make sure the job owner is a member of the aforementioned server roles so the job runs under the required security context. The job history will show the account actually used to run the job.

I suggest you use DMVs instead of deprecated system views.

```
SELECT
      @@SERVERNAME AS SQLServerName
    , @@SERVICENAME AS SQLInstanceName
    , logins.name as LoginName
FROM sys.server_principals AS logins
JOIN sys.server_role_members AS srm ON srm.member_principal_id = logins.principal_id
JOIN sys.server_principals AS server_roles ON server_roles.principal_id = srm.role_principal_id
WHERE 
     server_roles.name = 'sysadmin';
```